# feature-request: "oldest" sort view instead of "newest", and going to the end

Tags: feature-request, sorting, views

In question views, and on user pages you can look in order of votes, recent activity, and newest. I'd like to be able to reverse-sort by date stuff was added rather than have to go to the end and work my way back up through.